# Install third party software as a prerequisite software along with my application setup package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, setup-project

I created a Setup project for my Winforms application using Visual Studio 2013, to be installed at the client location. During this I found that the client needs to install a third party software as well for my application to work properly. 
How do I bundle my application with the third party executable file? so that when the client hits on Setup.exe to install my application should also install run and install the third party executable.

I was trying to add it as a prerequisite to my setup project using the Property Pages window of the setup project I see couple of options which I guess is not working as per my need.

Not sure if I am missing any step or doing it wrongly. Appreciate if anyone can guide me through a step by step approach for this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCeL8.png)

Comment: It would help to say exactly which prerequisite needs to be installed.

Comment: It's LabJack.exe we need this LabJack software to be on the client machine for my application to run without any issues. Also as we keep upgrading our software with latest features and release it to client, it would be good to install the Labjack software for the first time only.

Comment: Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.